# key password from Keystore

Tags: android, flutter

I've used this command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/nutella.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias nutella
```

to generate a Keystore. It works fine but From what I've read this command should also prompt you for a key password(not the store password)? I never got this prompt. 
I can run

```
keytool -v -list -keystore //nutella.jks
```

to see the contents of the Keystore. And the key seems to be there...ie the correct alias is there.
Where do I get/set the password for the the particular alias?

I have a key.properties in the android directory

```
storePassword=password
keyPassword=password
keyAlias=ballotbox
storeFile=/Users/gerardhorgan/ballotbox.jks
```

and in build.gradle I have:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "app.ballotbox.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}
```

When I try to generate a release build I get

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.                
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

I think it might have something to with keyPassword because I didn't set this and read somewhere you can use the storePassword.

`

Answer (score 0):

Try `android`, it's the default one.

Comment: that's for debug

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue is with the wrong alias.

In this code you have mentioned -alias = nutella at the end.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/nutella.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias nutella
```

But in key.properties you have `keyAlias=ballotbox`.

[Secondly, as per official guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app),

> The -storetype JKS tag is only required for Java 9 or newer. As of the Java 9 release, the keystore type defaults to PKS12.

That means, if you don't provide `-storetype JKS` in the command to generate keystore, the generated keystore file is of type PKS12 and not JKS. It seems in PKS12 format you can only set store password and the same password is used for key password during build. So, when I had different passwords set in key.properties file for store and key, I was getting "given-final-block-not-properly-padded" error, and no error when both were same.