# No key with alias 'upload' found in keystore C:\Users\alank\newapp\android\app\key.jks

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, google-play

### I created my first Flutter app, I want to publish the Android version, unfortunately, I get this error :

Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Failed to read key upload from store "C:\Users\alank\OneDrive\Desktop\flutter_app\new app\newapp\android\app\key.jks": No key with alias 'upload' found in keystore C:\Users\alank\OneDrive\Desktop\flutter_app\new app\newapp\android\app\key.jks

---

```
I create a key Properties file in android file :
storePassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
keyPassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
keyAlias=upload
storeFile= ../app/key.jks
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this command in a terminal to find out what are the aliases you use:

`keytool -v -list -keystore my.keystore`

Comment: hi stacktrace2234 thanks for answering me, I tried to use that command and I get this error:  java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: my.keystore

Comment: `my.keystore` should be replaced with your keystore: `key.jks`

Comment: I just did that, unfortunately, I still get the same issue, Do you know what could be the problem.

Comment: do you run that command in the folder where the key.jks file can be found?

Comment: I generated that in vs code then I copied it in the android/app in my project, so I runt that command in my project

Comment: Well, it does not find the file. You have to figure it out. Or just create a new jks file but remember the alias you used.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73292443/13627278). May be you have created keystore file with a wrong alias. Use the same "upload" alias at the end of the command used for generating keystore file.

Also in command `keytool -v -list -keystore key.jks`, you can find the exact path to key.jks (as well as for the keytool for those who face "keytool is not valid cmd command error"), or copy key.jks to a simpler path like in C: drive and execute the command as `C:\"Program Files"\Android\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\keytool -v -list -keystore C:\key.jks` to inspect it.