# Failed to read key from store

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to sign flutter app with upload key but getting error while generating app bundle/apk.

**command:**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "D:\Desktop\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

**key.properties:**

```
storePassword=1234567
keyPassword=1234567
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=D:/Desktop/upload-keystore2.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

**Error:**

```
> Failed to read key upload from store "D:\Desktop\upload-keystore2.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload": No key with alias 'upload' found in keystore D:\Desktop\upload-keystore2.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

****How to fix?****

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830541/no-key-with-alias-upload-found-in-keystore-c-users-alank-newapp-android-app-k